# Domain name coining issue

Tags: domains, name

I've found two keyword search from Google keyword tool:

- "K1 run"   (Phrase match,320,000 local monthly searches)
- "K2 run"   (75,000 local monthly searches)

K1,K2 are not dictionary word while run is.

Will it be ok to register domain: **K1runK2run**?

Or should I go with **K1K2run** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There's more to search engines in the world. Which do you think would make more sense to your actual users? I think k1k2run.

2) Doubling the keyword in the domain name probably doesn't benefit you at all. People will probably talk about keyword density and other stuff like that. But I would think the search engines are well aware of keyword stuffing and it applies to domain names as well.

Comment: For searchers k1runk2run will be more friendly. Are you saying say in this case it could be construed as keyword stuffing and possible penalty due to repeated keyword?

Comment: @John, why would k1runk2run be more friendly to searchers?

Comment: k1 run and k2 run always come together when in talk or writing or while searching. So I think of k1, run naturally always follows it. That's why I'm thinking it as natural for the domain name to be K1runK2run.

Comment: @John, if people do in fact use k1run2run the way you say then k1runk2run is good usability for your users and you should use that. Having run in your domain won't help or hurt you so definitely do what's best usability wise.

Comment: I'll be honest it's an ugly looking and unmemorable name, I'd try go for something else. I keep reading it as `runk`

Answer (score 0):

I think K1run.com is best.  The shorter the better - for users and for seo.

If you want to target the other keyword use a subfolder... k1run.com/K2

Good luck.